# Create all possible combinations of non unique integers in an array C++

Tags: c++, bigdata

I have a hotel management app with a booking module. I'd like to be able to compute possible room combinations for large groups.

I have an array of all room capacities currently available. The array below would depict 10 free rooms: 2 single bed, 2 double bed etc.

`int currenylyAvailableRooms [10] = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5 };`

Id like to query this array and find out if a combination of rooms exists to house `x` guests. For example, I'd like to know if there exists a combination which would fit 21 guests. (For the above example it would return `true` with eg. 5,5,4,4,2,1 - there may be more than 1 combination.

> Keep in mind a hotel can be very large and have 20 single rooms (20 x
>   1 in the array) and 10 suites which can fit 10 people (10 x 10 in the
>   array) with the `currenylyAvailableRooms` array having even 100 elements.

I'm a little worried that this is a rather time consuming calculation when the array has 100 elements so I'd be more than happy to run it every time the array changes and store all possible combinations in a database if needed.

**My question is this: how would I find possible combinations of elements in the array which sum to a specified integer OR how do I calculate all possible combinations**

Comment: what is the question? yes it is time consuming to go trough all possible combinations. You only have to consider combinations with the correct total number of beds you are looking for

Comment: btw why would there be 10 x 1 in the array for 20 single rooms?

Comment: and why would there be 100 elements in the array for 10 suites?

Comment: @user463035818 There would be 100 elements for a hotel which has 10 rooms which fit 1 person, 10 rooms which fit 2 people, 10 rooms which fit 3 people [..] 10 rooms which fit 10 people.

Comment: this can be considered as a variation of the [knappsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) about which you can find many solutions online

Comment: This sounds kind of like the traveling salesmen problem.  If it is, you are going to need to check all possible combinations.

Comment: @user463035818 Interesting, I'll have a read about that

Comment: @NathanOliver how would I calculate all possible combinations in the fastest possible time?

Comment: @Cellydy What you have is actually far from _"big data"_.

Comment: The trick to questions like this is usually to find ways to *avoid* computing all of the possibilities.

Comment: `std::next_permutation` can be used to permute a set one combination at a time until you get back to the original.

Comment: do you need to find one combination or all combinations?

Comment: @user463035818 I'd be more than happy with 1 combination

Comment: this is a real life problem? haha, sounds very much like an online exercise/contest that is trying to push you to dynamic programming

Comment: @user463035818 Yes it's a real life problem. It's a feature I'd like to implement in a hotel booking app.

Comment: Would you like to minimize or maximize the number of rooms in the single solution found?  For example is `{3, 4, 4, 5, 5}` preferred over `{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5}`?

Comment: @HowardHinnant Minimizing would be much preferred!

Comment: Perhaps [`for_each_combination`](https://howardhinnant.github.io/combinations.html) would be useful to you then.  Although it is fast, it is still brute force.  However it allows you to stop the search once a solution is found.  And you can search for combinations of N items K at a time in order of increasing K, stopping when you've found a solution.  When solutions are rare, this is a 2<sup>N</sup> complexity algorithm though.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that for N available rooms, a given room is either part of the selection or it is not, hence you have 2^N different selections in total. They can be depicted in a tree diagram

```
                                   x
                                  / \
                                 /   \
                                x     1
                               / \   / \
                              /  |   |  \
                             x   2   1   1+2
```

where going right means "the room is in" and going left means "the room is not in" and the nodes are labeled with the total number of guests for the selected rooms. For example when you don't pick room 1 and you don't pick room 2 then total sum is 0, when you do pick room one and you do pick room 2 then you add capacity of room one with capacity of room 2 (labeled as `1+2`).

The trick is now to not traverse all branches till the end, but only till

a) the sum is the desired number of guests => you have a solution. No need to go deeper in the tree.

b) the sum is bigger than the desired number of guests. Again no need to go deeper in the tree, as we are only adding more space.

c) you reached the end of a branch and still not enough space.

In all three cases you can go back upwards in the tree until you reach a node with a downwards path that you didnt take already. Proceed along this path and repeat until you found one (or all if you like) solution.

This is just the basic idea. There can be many variations on how to travel trough the tree and you can save quite something when you sort the input array and use the fact that several rooms can hold the same amount of guests.

On the other hand, an array with 10 elements is relatively small. Even considering combinatorics, where usually the factorial is the killer, `10! = 3628800` is still within reasonable bounds and maybe a simple brute force algorithm is sufficient. However, `100!` is already a completely different story ;).